# Amazon S3 metadata key being prefixed , how to avoid this?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I have code which writes to something to s3 bucket.

```
 PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
 titledRequest.WithMetaData("Eip1", "Volume-1")
.WithMetaData("Eip2", "Volume-2")
 .WithContentBody("this is an Elastic IP Address Details for a Volumes")
  .WithBucketName(bucketName)
 .WithKey(keyName);
```

and read it using

```
   AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID,  secretAccessKeyID);

 GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest().WithBucketName(bucketName).WithKey(keyName);

    string title = response.Metadata.Get("Eip1");
```

but getting null in return , when debugged i saw response.Metadata.Keys have

x-amz-meta-eip1
&  x-amz-meta-eip2

**How this keys are being renamed , How to Avoid this ?**

Why they are being prefixed with  **x-amz-meta-**

Answer (score 2):

They are prefixed this way by design "to distinguish them as custom HTTP headers"

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?UsingMetadata.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use .WithMetadata, s3 client always prefixes the metadata with x-amz-meta. If you want to specify System metadata, like Cache Control headers, use .AddHeaders on the request:

```
            var rq = (PutObjectRequest) new PutObjectRequest()
                                            .WithKey(fileName)
                                            .WithBucketName(BucketName)
                                            .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
                                            .WithInputStream(source);
            rq.AddHeaders(new WebHeaderCollection
                              {
                                  {HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache"}
                              });
```